# Tensorflow automatically choose least loaded GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

We specify the GPU device to be used using:

```
with tf.device('/gpu:'+gpu_id):
```

gpu_id is a string variable where I manually set the GPU id to be used.
I need to run several experiments, each on a different GPU. So, I manually change the value of gpu_id before running a code instance.

Can I write some code that automatically detects the first unutilized GPU and set it to gpu_id ?

Comment: Yes, you have to write that code manually. Probably the easiest thing is to have a static allocation for your experiments and use `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to pin an experiment to a GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a function that allows you to know which GPU is being used for a tensor:

```
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

Setting `log_device_placement` to `True` will return data similar to this:

```
Device mapping:
/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 -> device: 0, name: Tesla K40c, pci bus
id: 0000:05:00.0
b: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
a: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
MatMul: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0
[[ 22.  28.]
 [ 49.  64.]]
```

↳ [Using GPUs](https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/using_gpu/)

Comment: Thanks. But how to use this to determine which GPU is not utilized during run-time ?

Comment: `a` and `b` show which gpu is being used, in the example above neither one is. If one was though it would look like this `/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:1 -> device: 1` (see the last example on the page I linked: https://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/using_gpu/)

Answer (score 1):

I am working on TF-2.1 and torch, so I don't want to specific this automacit choosing in any ML frame. I just use original **nvidia-smi** and **os.environ** to get a vacant gpu.

```
def auto_gpu_selection(usage_max=0.01, mem_max=0.05):
"""Auto set CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES for gpu

:param mem_max: max percentage of GPU utility
:param usage_max: max percentage of GPU memory
:return:
"""
os.environ['CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER'] = 'PCI_BUS_ID'
log = str(subprocess.check_output("nvidia-smi", shell=True)).split(r"\n")[6:-1]
gpu = 0

# Maximum of GPUS, 8 is enough for most
for i in range(8):
    idx = i*3 + 2
    if idx > log.__len__()-1:
        break
    inf = log[idx].split("|")
    if inf.__len__() < 3:
        break
    usage = int(inf[3].split("%")[0].strip())
    mem_now = int(str(inf[2].split("/")[0]).strip()[:-3])
    mem_all = int(str(inf[2].split("/")[1]).strip()[:-3])
    # print("GPU-%d : Usage:[%d%%]" % (gpu, usage))
    if usage < 100*usage_max and mem_now < mem_max*mem_all:
        os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_EVICES"] = str(gpu)
        print("\nAuto choosing vacant GPU-%d : Memory:[%dMiB/%dMiB] , GPU-Util:[%d%%]\n" %
              (gpu, mem_now, mem_all, usage))
        return
    print("GPU-%d is busy: Memory:[%dMiB/%dMiB] , GPU-Util:[%d%%]" %
          (gpu, mem_now, mem_all, usage))
    gpu += 1
print("\nNo vacant GPU, use CPU instead\n")
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_EVICES"] = "-1"
```

If I can get any GPU, it will set **CUDA_VISIBLE_EVICES** to BUSID of that gpu :

```
GPU-0 is busy: Memory:[5738MiB/11019MiB] , GPU-Util:[60%]
GPU-1 is busy: Memory:[9688MiB/11019MiB] , GPU-Util:[78%]

Auto choosing vacant GPU-2 : Memory:[1MiB/11019MiB] , GPU-Util:[0%]
```

else, set to **-1** to use CPU:

```
GPU-0 is busy: Memory:[8900MiB/11019MiB] , GPU-Util:[95%]
GPU-1 is busy: Memory:[4674MiB/11019MiB] , GPU-Util:[35%]
GPU-2 is busy: Memory:[9784MiB/11016MiB] , GPU-Util:[74%]

No vacant GPU, use CPU instead
```

**Note**: Use this function **before** you import any ML frame that require a GPU, then it can automatically choose a gpu. Besides, it's easy for you to set multiple tasks.